# List of Instagram Media

Tags: instagram

How can I get a list of an Instagram account media (photos and videos)?

Can I do this without programming?

Comment: Are you trying to get a dump of your own account data, or a full copy of somebody else's?

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

Instagram by design does not allow you to do this.

They do have an API however (Docs here: http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/media/ ) which with a bit of programming will allow you to get what you want.

As for doing it without programming, unless someone knows of a secret URL, then as far as I'm aware it's impossible.

Even doing it by web scraping (Without using the API) would require some level of programming to get the data.